# SQL Server - Most recent date and sale amount columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 to complete a query. I have a sale table that contains a unique sale id, a customer id, a sale date, and a sale amount. I'm trying to create a table that has the most recent sale for each customer and the amount for that sale.

```
| customer_id | most recent sale date | sale amount |
|     1       |2012-06-11 00:00:00.000|     150     |
|     2       |2012-01-07 00:00:00.000|     55      |
|     3       |2012-02-18 00:00:00.000|     117     |
|     4       |2012-09-02 00:00:00.000|     25      |
```

I have the first two columns with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, MAX(sale_date)
FROM sale
GROUP BY customer_id
```

When I try to add the amount of the sale, everything I try includes every sale for that customer, not just the most recent one. Is there a way to do this? Keep in mind there is a unique sale id on this table that might be of some use. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with `PARTITION BY` in a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT sale_id,customer_id,sale_date, sale_amount
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY sale_date DESC)
   FROM sale
)
SELECT sale_id, customer_id, sale_date, sale_amount
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Here's a sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/513280/1/0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.customer_id, a.sale_date, a.sale_amount
FROM    sale a 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT   customer_id, MAX(sale_date) maxSale
            FROM     sale
            GROUP BY customer_id
        ) b ON  a.customer_ID = b.customer_ID AND
                a.sale_date = b.maxSale
```

Comment: This solution will fail if there are two orders for one customer on the same day.  It will return two records for that customer.

Answer (score 0):

By just using Aggregate function MAX in an independent subquery worked for me.

```
SELECT Customerid, Saleid, Sldate AS 'Most Recent Sale', Saleamount
FROM Sale S1
WHERE Sldate = (SELECT MAX(Sldate) FROM Sale S2);
```

Using Aliases is a mandatory step.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,SALE_AMOUNT,SALEDATE FROM SALE WHERE SALEDATE =(SELECT MAX(SALEDATE) FROM SALE);